# How to change SwiftUI alert color scheme?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have implemented a functionality that changes the color scheme of the app. Everything works fine except the color scheme for the `.alert()` that has a `TextField` in it.

If is daylight and color scheme is changed to `.dark`, the `.alert()` color scheme is still `.light` includind the `TextField`.

That means that when you type something in the `TextField`, the foreground color is white, because the text color in dark mode changes to white, and you can't really see what you are typing.

Similar, if the system's color scheme is `.dark` and the app's color scheme is white, the `.alert` is in `.dark` mode and the text is black, because the text in the app is black.

Applying `.background()` or `foregroundColor()` to `TextField` or `VStack` doesn't have any effect.

Is there a way to control the color scheme for `.alert()`? Or do I have to look for an `.alert()` alternative?

Here is some code to reproduce the bahaviour. Thanks!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showAlert = false
    @State private var addSomething: String = ""
    @State private var isSystemMode = false
    @State private var isDarkMode = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Toggle("Automatic (iOS Settings)", isOn: $isSystemMode)
                if !isSystemMode {
                    Toggle("Dark Mode", isOn: $isDarkMode)
                }
            }
            Button{
                self.showAlert = true
            } label: {
                Text("Add something")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            }
            .alert("Add something", isPresented: $showAlert, actions: {
                TextField("Something", text: $addSomething)
                Button("Done") {
                    // Some action
                }
                Button("Cancel", role: .cancel, action: {})
            }, message: {
                Text("Type in something")
            })
        }
        .padding()
        .preferredColorScheme(isSystemMode ? .none : isDarkMode ? .dark : .light)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: I've faced the same problem. There doesn't seem to be a good way to "dynamically" change this on the fly. You can change in an init with this approach UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).tintColor but I ended up making my own custom alert views instead which is relatively easy.

Comment: @bjorn.lau, I have tried with UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).tintColor but that changes the color of the buttons on alert, also the navigation buttons, etc. Is not changing the background color. I've seen something abput a custom alert from few years back, just wondering if since them things changed or not. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yea, you would have to target all the things you need to change, so .tintColor will not be enough. But yea, I think the problem is those Alerts are not native SwiftUI, they are really UIAlertControllers under the hood

Comment: @bjorn.lau, I didn't know Alerts are not native SwiftUI. What does it tell you from documentation that is UIAlertControllers? Don't get me wrong, I just want to learn more, including reading the documentation.

Comment: Well, the fact that you can modify it with UIAlertController kind of shows that it's really still UIKit under the hood, but I have not investigated a whole lot: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller

Comment: I just added the one I ended up making instead, the cool thing about that one is that you can include any content you want in it (which is very limited on the other alert). It can probably be made better, but it works. So instead instead of the regular .alert you just add this view in a ZStack and add and remove it when you want to show the alert.

Comment: Modified my answer to include a better example of how to use it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only way to truly make this work is by making your own custom alert. Here is an example of a custom alert, but you might have to modify it according to your needs:

```
struct CustomAlertView<Content: View>: View {

    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    let title: String
    let description: String

    var cancelAction: (() -> Void)?
    var cancelActionTitle: String?

    var primaryAction: (() -> Void)?
    var primaryActionTitle: String?

    var customContent: Content?

    init(title: String,
         description: String,
         cancelAction: (() -> Void)? = nil,
         cancelActionTitle: String? = nil,
         primaryAction: (() -> Void)? = nil,
         primaryActionTitle: String? = nil,
         customContent: Content? = EmptyView()) {
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.cancelAction = cancelAction
        self.cancelActionTitle = cancelActionTitle
        self.primaryAction = primaryAction
        self.primaryActionTitle = primaryActionTitle
        self.customContent = customContent
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                Text(title)
                    .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .semibold, design: .default))
                    .padding(.top)
                    .padding(.bottom, 8)

                Text(description)
                    .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .light, design: .default))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding([.bottom, .trailing, .leading])

                customContent

                Divider()

                HStack {
                    if let cancelAction, let cancelActionTitle {
                        Button { cancelAction() } label: {
                            Text(cancelActionTitle)
                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                        }
                    }

                    if cancelActionTitle != nil && primaryActionTitle != nil {
                        Divider()
                    }

                    if let primaryAction, let primaryActionTitle {
                        Button { primaryAction() } label: {
                            Text("**\(primaryActionTitle)**")
                                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                        }
                    }
                }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 50, alignment: .center)
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 400, alignment: .center)
            .background(.ultraThickMaterial)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .padding([.trailing, .leading], 50)
        }
        .zIndex(1)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        .background(
            colorScheme == .dark
            ? Color(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, opacity: 0.4)
            : Color(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, opacity: 0.4)
        )
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Button("Show alert") {
                withAnimation {
                    showAlert.toggle()
                }
            }
            if showAlert {
                CustomAlertView(
                    title: "Alert title",
                    description: "Description here",
                    cancelAction: {
                        // Cancel action here
                        withAnimation {
                            showAlert.toggle()
                        }
                    },
                    cancelActionTitle: "Cancel",
                    primaryAction: {
                      // Primary action here
                        withAnimation {
                            showAlert.toggle()
                        }
                    },
                    primaryActionTitle: "Action",
                    customContent:
                        Text("Custom content here")
                        .padding([.trailing, .leading, .bottom])
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to include a TextField simply do:

```
customContent:
    TextField("Text here", text: $text)
    .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
    .padding([.trailing, .leading, .bottom])
```

[image: Preview of custom alert]

Comment: This is really good answer. I've just tested it and works amazing. I only need to do some tweaks for my purpose. Thank you very much for taking your time to answer!